# rnfirebase on react native app don't work

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I have this dependencies:

```
"react-native": "0.62.2",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^7.0.1",
"@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^7.0.1",
```

In my project I have done rnfirebase structure on my existing project from this url:
[react native firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage)

I have added this:

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    // ... other dependencies
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    // Add me --- /\
  }
}
```

To my build.gradle

And this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

To my app/build.gradle also placed downloaded google-services.json from firebase console in /app directory

Then I have used firestore package like this:

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('on load');

    firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .add({
        name: 'Hello firebase',
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log('success');
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err, 'error'));
  });
```

In my app, but noting appears no xhr connection made in react native debugger no console log error or success! Nothing!

I have done uninstall rnfirebase/app and rnfirebase/firestore packages and uninstalled then rebuild app by react-native run-android but nothing happened!

Comment: Check if apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' is placed at the BOTTOM of android/app/build.gradle   /    Also check that you ran this command: npm install @react-native-firebase/app

Comment: Yes I have done both

Comment: Test if you have the rules for cloud firestore enabled to write and read.

Comment: Thank you @MIPB it was emulators internet connection I put the answer on the bottom

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for three days I just fount the problem and it was emulators internet connection!!

With google search app I had network connection, but on my app there was no internet connection to connect to firebase!
So the solution was to run emulator on specific dns by this command:

```
emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_29  -dns-server 8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 0):

i found that i was getting the firebase errors when i use 'pixel emulators' even when i did the firebase installments just fine but the 'Nexus_6' works perfectly given that you follow the proper firebase installment guideline...

Soooo, try using the Nexus emulators instead.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).